# How to deal with absolute values of the independent variable in a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the differential equation $4x\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=y^2-4$. This is a separable equation so after integrating I get $\ln \left(\frac{2-y}{2+y}\right)=\ln|x|+C$.

Now, raising $e$ to the power of both sides and doing some algebra gives me $y=\frac{2(1-e^C|x|)}{1+e^C|x|}$. This function is obviously not differentiable when $x=0$ so it can't be a solution to the differential equation. However, I can seperate the solution into cases which gives me:

$y=\begin{cases}
\frac{2(1-e^Cx)}{1+e^Cx} & x>0 \\ 
\frac{2(1+e^Cx)}{1-e^Cx} & x<0
 \end{cases}$

However, checking the solution on wolfram alpha I only get the positive solution for all $x$, including $x=0$. I understand that the positive solution satisfies the differential equation even when $x=0$, but what is the justification for just ignoring the absolute value like that? Also, I know that sometimes the two cases for the solution can agree by taking a different constant for each case but here, the constant term is always positive so the solutions can't agree simply by taking different constants, so why can we just ignore the different solution for $x<0$?

P.S. I know that similar questions have been asked here about this subject but reading the answers to them didn't help me realize the answer to my question, so I decided to ask it anyway. Besides, most of these questions deal with cases where $y$ is also taken inside an absolute value which is a bit different from the case in hand here.

Answer (score 1):

You in fact get the absolute value on both sides.
$$
\ln \left|\frac{2-y}{2+y}\right|=\ln|x|+c
$$
Solving this introduces a sign that can be combined with the positive factor $e^c$ to give $C=\pm e^c$. 
$$
\frac{2-y}{2+y}=Cx\implies y=2\frac{1-Cx}{1+Cx}
$$
Along each segment of the solution, inside the domain where the differential equation is not singular, the sign of all these factors is constant, so that indeed there is only one constant $C$ on each such segment. For an IVP, $C$ along with its sign is determined by the initial conditions.

Comment: Why would I get the absolute value on both sides? On the LHS I have the integral $\int \frac{1}{y^2-4}dy = -\frac{1}{4} \int \frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2}dy = -\frac{1}{2}\tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{4}\ln \left( \frac{2-y}{2+y}\right)$ which wouldn't give me an absolute value. Am I missing something?

Comment: That formula is only valid for $|y|<2$. Outside the sign of the fraction in the logarithmic argument is negative.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=\begin{cases}
\frac{2(1-e^Cx)}{1+e^Cx} & x>0 \\ 
\frac{2(1+e^Cx)}{1-e^Cx} & x<0
 \end{cases}$$
Is the same as:
$$y=
\frac{2(1+kx)}{1-kx} 
$$
For $k \in \mathbb R$

Comment: What about the case where $x=0$ though?

Comment: Look at the original equation when $x=0$ @olef,  You need initial conditions  for the interval of $x$

Comment: Also, and I should've mentioned it in the post, in the answer that wolfram alpha gives the constant is also always positive. The solution they give is $y=\frac{2(1-e^cx)}{1+e^cx}$ . How does this agree with the solution for the two cases?

Comment: I don't know for Worlfram alpha it's a software though...you just need to note that $-e^c=k$  @OfekAman

Comment: Of course it's only a software but I'm trying to realize what the right answer to this differential equation would be and why and generally Wolfram Alpha is very credible. Besides, I checked on MATLAB and got the exact same result I got from Wolfram. I must say I'm a bit confused about the sign of the constant here...

Comment: I guess most softwares use nearly the same algorithms.

Comment: With WA the result makes often more sense if you force the integration constants to be solved for an initial condition. So extending the query to `4*x*y'(x)=y(x)^2-4, y(1)=a` results in the solution `y(x) = (2 (a x + a - 2 x + 2))/(a (-x) + a + 2 x + 2)`. Also remember that WA solves everything in the complex domain, so that $e^c$ can be any real or complex value (except zero).